# Dart SDK version error when I use docker, mine is up to date

Tags: flutter, docker, dart, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM cirrusci/flutter:stable

COPY . /dia
WORKDIR /dia
RUN flutter pub get
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["flutter", "run", "--web-port", "80"]
```

When I give the command `docker build -t dia-app` . , it ends up giving an error in the Dart SDK version, saying that the version is 2.19.4 , and when I give dart --version , it returns 3.1.0, being the same for flutter --version

Below is the error

```
=> [3/4] WORKDIR /dia                                                                                                         0.1s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN flutter pub get                                                                                            2.6s
------
 > [4/4] RUN flutter pub get:
0.511    Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
0.511    We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
0.511   /
0.511 
1.120 Running "flutter pub get" in dia...
1.348 Resolving dependencies...
1.446 The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.4.
1.446
1.446 Because dia requires SDK version >=3.0.6 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
2.534 pub get failed
2.534 command: "/sdks/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
2.534 pub env: {
2.534   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/sdks/flutter",
2.534   "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_bot:flutter_cli:get",
2.534   "PUB_CACHE": "/root/.pub-cache",
2.534 }
2.534 exit code: 1
2.534
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------  
  4 | >>> RUN flutter pub get
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c flutter pub get" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I already reinstalled flutter, dart, flutter doctor, etc. Perhaps the error has to do with docker.

I use windows 11 and installed docker desktop